# PLSQL procedure to populate qty based on previous record values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a following table

```
- ITEM_NUMBER QTY_FROM QTY_TO
 - ABC           10
 - ABC           20
 - ABC           30
 - DEF           100
 - DEF           250
 - DEF           400
```

I need to write a plsql procedure which will populate `QTY_to` column based on `qty_from` next row for same item number.
for example if item number is `ABC` and `qty_from` is 10 on first row and 20 on next row....id expect the procedure to look at second row...and populate `qty_from` on the first one as 19 (next_row_qty_from - 1).

Comment: your question is not clear , you want to check if qty_from =10 and 2nd row qty_from =20 then first row will be 19 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ITEM_NUMBER, QTY_FROM, 
       lead(QTY_FROM, 1) over (partition by ITEM_NUMBER, order by QTY_FROM) - 1 as QTY_TO 
  from table;
```

As a third parameter to `lead` function you can add default value. This will be used when no next row exist for given `ITEM_NUMBER` so in case of row `- ABC           30` if you do `lead(QTY_FROM, 1, QTY_FROM)` there will be `29` as `QTY_TO` but you haven;t defined edge case in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No procedure needed, just simple update:

```
update t 
  set qty_to = 
    (select min(qty_from)-1 from t t2 
      where item_number = t.item_number and qty_from > t.qty_from)
```

---

Result:

```
SQL> select * from t order by item_number, qty_from;

ITEM_NUMBER QTY_FROM  QTY_TO
----------- -------- -------
ABC               10      19
ABC               20      29
ABC               30 
DEF              100     249
DEF              250     399
DEF              400 

6 rows selected
```